# How to pass 2D array from one activity to another(including all the info the array contains)

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I have a 2D array setup in Activity A which I would then like to use in activity B.
I have looked at varying examples online but cant get any to work properly.

The code below compiles OK but I get an error with my Toast of `java.lang.nullpointerexception.`
so it looks to me as if my array structure is being passed through but the contents are `null`.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far.:

Activity A

```
String[][] Question=new String[100][100];

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("questionset", Question);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B

```
    try{

        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String[][] Questions = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("questionset");        
        Toast.makeText(this, Questions[2][1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve those problems always with a storage object class which is a singleton and where i can save such objects.

```
public class Model
{
    private static Model instance;

    private Model()
    {
        // singleton implementation
    }

    /**
     * Returns a valid instance of the model.
     * 
     * @return THE instance of the model.
     */
    public static Model getInstance()
    {

        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Model();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private String[][] arr;
    // + getter and setter methods for arr
}
```

Comment: hmmm perhaps I should've mentioned in the main question that I'm very new(3 weeks) to android/java programming. In other words whats a singleton :S

If I were to stick to something similar to what I have already, is this a valid way to achieve the task? and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: A singleton is a design pattern [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Actually you could do it without using a singleton but only with a static class with static fields but a singleton looks nicer to me. YOu can just copy&paste the code above and add getter and setter methods for the array arr. You can then use this class by calling Model.getInstance.getArray() for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] Question=new String[100][100]; 
Question[2][1]="sample";    // here
Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
b.putSerializable("questionset", Question); 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class); 
intent.putExtras(b);    // here
startActivity(intent);
```

Your code lacks initialization of array contents and passing it to intent. Is it intentional? For me the above code works pretty well.

Comment: i intentionally removed that part of code from my question as its quite cumbersome but I am 100% sure that within activity A all array values are populated, I have tested to check.

Comment: I've added the following to Activity A...
intent.putExtras(b);

and now i get a java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; error.
Im not sure if thats a step forward or backward :s